Filter causes measure to fail
I am relatively new to PBI and having difficulty debugging this DAX.
SRS Seat Change = 
Var Startdate = SELECTEDVALUE('Combined data'[Source Date])

Var Prevdate =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( 'Combined data'[Source Date]),
        ALLSELECTED('Combined data'),
        KEEPFILTERS('Combined data'[Source Date] < Startdate)
    )
Var Result =
   CALCULATE(
        SUM(
        'Combined data'[Seats]),
        'Combined data'[Source] = "MNL",
   
        'Combined data'[Source Date] = Prevdate
    )
RETURN

IF(
    result <> 0,
    IFERROR(
        [SRS Seats] - Result,
        blank()
)
)

My matrix table has 2 or more columns which are dates and the above needs to calculate the difference between the columns.  if I put a filter on the matrix table the calculation does not work unless I change Prevdate above to a hard coded date so = value("01/01/2024).  It does however work fine if I do not filter the Matrix table.
I have tried to keepfliters, allselected but nothing seems to work.
What am I missing?  appreciate any help you can offer.

Try like this instead:
SRS Seat Change = 
VAR StartDate = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Combined data'[Source Date]),
        ALL('Combined data')
    )

VAR PrevDate =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Combined data'[Source Date]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Combined data'),
            'Combined data'[Source Date] < StartDate
        )
    )

VAR Result =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Combined data'[Seats]),
    'Combined data'[Source] = "MNL",
        FILTER(
            ALL('Combined data'),
            'Combined data'[Source Date] = PrevDate
        )
    )


RETURN

IF(
    result <> 0,
    IFERROR(
        [SRS Seats] - Result,
        blank()
)
)


Thanks for the edit above.  I still have the same problem, it only calculates the difference between the 2 columns if I hard code the Previous date.  Both columns have the correct figures, but the subtraction does not work.

It works for me. Do you have a slicer in the report where you choose "'Combined data'[Source Date]" ?. The SELECTEDVALUE function expects a value from a Slicer because it needs to know what the context is. So in your case it is the variable "Startdate" that is causing you the issue unless you supply it with a value.

I don't have a slicer per se, but the table is filtered on many fields.  When this filter is applied the calculation fails.  It seems to ignore the filter in the calculations even though both columns contain the correct filtered data.

It ignores the filter because it doesn't understand what the Start date should be based on since you don't select anything.
Add a slicer to your report with this field and try:
'Combined data'[Source Date].

Problem is there may be several source dates.  Basically, it should compare the data from 3 source files.  Is it easier if I share the PBIX here?

Yes if it is possible share it !

I thought I could attach the file to the comments, but that does not seem possible.  I don't even think i can send a screen shot of the filters

What do you wish your Startdate to be ?
Var Startdate = SELECTEDVALUE('Combined data'[Source Date]) ?

It should be the date in the column before. If there are 3 columns 3/8/23, 10/9/23 and 15/9/23, the start dates would be 3/8/23 to calculate the seat difference between 3/8 and 10/9, it will also then be 10/9 to calculate the seat difference between 10/9 and the 15/9.  This off course will not work if you hard code the date, if hard coded you can only have 2 source files.  The original dax works but does not recognize any filters.  Each line in the underlying data has a date the date of the schedule.  I am trying to calculate the seat changes between source dates, and filter the schedule dates

I have altered the VAR to
Var Result =
  CALCULATE(
        sumx('Combined data','Combined data'[Seats]),
        'Combined data'[Sched Date] > value("29/02/2024"),
        'Combined data'[Sched Date] < VALUE("01/01/2025"),
        
    'Combined data'[Source Date] = Prevdate
  ) 
RETURN

which get around the problem but I want to be able to select the [Sched Date] from the filter.  Hope all this makes sense.

I modified the answer with the whole code. Try and see if it works for you.

Thanks for all your efforts.  The latest version does not work, it calculates the difference between the whole table and the latest file.  I think I need to go back to the drawing board.
